# Jenkins user cannot run composer install

Tags: php, linux, jenkins, composer-php

I am trying to run the composer installer from Jenkins project folder as Jenkins user.

```
/usr/local/bin/composer install
```

I get the message

```
Content-type: text/html

Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /usr/local/bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

I don't know why it is looking for `composer.json` inside `usr/local/bin`.

If I run this as the root user it works. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

this is my environment

```
pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project_staging
whoami
jenkins
```

Comment: The first message already looks wrong - what does `php -v` return?

Comment: When I run php -v as root user I get PHP 5.4.45 (cli) but when I run as Jenkins user I get PHP 5.4.45 (cgi-fcgi) . Do yo know how I can make them use the same php? Not very familiar with Linux.

Comment: @HarlanGray Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install composer using the following instructions:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php56
```

In order to avoid any issues

```
cd ~/bin
ln -s /usr/local/bin/php56 php
```

Modify your ~/.bash_profile file and change:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin To `PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`
```

Then close your SSH session and start a new one, or run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then ~/bin path will then take precedence and you will be using the correct version of PHP.

Comment: thanks for you answer Nithin. I did as you said. When I run php -v as root user I get PHP 5.4.45 (cli)  but when I run as Jenkins user I get PHP 5.4.45 (cgi-fcgi) . Why is that? To change to Jenkins user I have to use "sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins" Just "su Jenkins" doesn't work as I have seen in some tutorials. Is there something wrong with my setup?